# How to exclude a specific file from a rewriterule

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have been here: [How to exclude a specific file in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185349/how-to-exclude-a-specific-file-in-htaccess)

and here: [exclude files from rewrite rule in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839537/exclude-files-from-rewrite-rule-in-htaccess)

but neither worked. What might I be doing wrong?

.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wp-content(/.*|)$ - [L] # don't take any action
RewriteRule ^wp-admin(/.*|)$ - [L] # don't take any action
RewriteRule ^wp-includes(/.*|)$ - [L] # don't take any action
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pureplantessentials\.html$

RewriteRule ^moreinfo/(.*)$ http://www.kgstiles.com/moreinfo$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^healthsolutions/(.*)$ http://www.kgstiles.com/healthsolutions$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1/ [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: ¿Rewrite from what to what? Some examples please. From your rule set it's impossible to guess.

Comment: I want to exclude a specific file from the rest of my rules. I'll post my htaccess file in an edit above.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To exclude a file, try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pureplantessentials\.html$
```

The rule will be skipped if the file is `pureplantessentials.html`.

Comment: it is still rewriting. Is there a specific place it should be? I put it at the end of my exclusions...

Comment: That's why an example is important. Please update your answer with an example to see how the incoming URL with the file to exclude looks.

Comment: Should I post my updated .htaccess file and show you how it looks?

Comment: I just posted my htaccess file in my question. www.kgstiles.com/pureplantessentials.html still redirects to www.kgstiles.com/pureplantessentials/

Comment: Of course. You are excluding that file from applying the rules, that's why the requested URL remains the same. If you try with another file name the rules should be applied but they aren't either, because the conditions in the rule itself are not met, so the last rule (Repeated) applies and nothing is modified.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was a mistake by you or if something I did was contrary to what I said above, but by changing RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pureplantessentials\.html$ to RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^pureplantessentials\.html$ (without the first /), I was able to make this work.

Comment: Both had the same idea. The difference is the position of the directory inside the URI. I assumed it was the first subdirectory, but it isn't. Glad you found out the way to make it work.

Comment: What if it's a PHP file that's already being redirected to based on a previous rewrite rule?