apache 2.4, mod_rewite, htaccess: RewriteRule in <IF>
Got an inherited problem from a retired admin. We have a 1900+ line .htaccess and I have to consolidate as a first step.
Instead of writing 700 times
RewriteCond
RewriteRule
I'd like to group the requests according to the HTTP_HOST into sections of <if> statements:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.my-domain.com'">
  RewriteRule ^hta-test(/(index\.php)?)?$   https://www.hmy-domain.de/de/RewriteRule.php [NC,R=301,L]
</If>

But the RewriteRule is not executed. If I use "RewriteMatch", this works (this tells me that the "<IF>" works in general). but the function of the "L" Flag isn't present but required.
How do I make "RewriteRule" in <IF> work in Apache 2.4.9 CentOS 7.9?
Or is there a functional analogue in mod_alias?
Kind Regards
Maniac_
PS: I know, 1900 line htaccess is crap.

Hey folks... No idear? Would also accept a "Will not work, because XYZ, try ABC instead."

Negating the condition and using a rule with the skip flag could be an option - although not a very convenient one, since it depends on the exact number of rules to skip, so any further modification could become a p.i.t.a. [...]

[...] Funny enough, it says right there, "It is probably easier to accomplish this kind of configuration using the , , and  directives instead." - and that's below an example using RewriteRules, so I am not sure why this should not work. Maybe enable some rewrite logging, and see if that can bring any further enlightenment?

On a way to find a step forward: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61247650/grouping-rewriterule-by-rewritecond-with-htaccess
This works with leading "/":  'RewriteRule /about/$' but also matches "FALSE/about/$" or "/FALSE/about/$" which is not intended. The $ operator works, BUT "^" operator seems to FAIL and the line is not machted. Tested with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Apache/2.4.58.

Solution: In ... RewriteRule matches the filepath (/var/www/html/hta-test), not the URL-path.
Not my favorite, but it's ok. Is this intended?

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule:
Per-directory Rewrites:

The If blocks follow the rules of the directory context.

BUT WHY?
