# Remove .php except for some file in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, rewriting

I have successfully written .htaccess code to remove .php from the url's however i want to add an exception and keep it there for some of the files (e.g. www.mysite.com/samples.php).

I have tried so many rules but nothing worked. Can somebody help me out.

I want to have an exception there as well so that it allows .php in some of the files and remove it from the others that do not lie in the exception rule.

Regards

Comment: Take a look at excluding the files with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839537/exclude-files-from-rewrite-rule-in-htaccess

Comment: Please post the rules you have used to remove the `.php` extension, and what you have tried that didn't work.

Comment: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.php [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php [L]

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to keep it there?

Do you need to add a variable to the url if so then you could do this in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^samples/(.*)/(.*)$ samples.php?var1=$1&var2=$2
```